# Php add elements in array at specific position

Tags: php, arrays

I have an empty array in PHP and some datas i need to push in this empty array.

For each data i have `$data->getName()`, `$data->getValue()` and `$data->getPosition()` so i have :

```
        foreach($datas as $key => $data){
            array_push($myEmptyArray, array($data->getName() . ":" . $data->getValue() ));
        }
```

I get something like that :

```
[["lastname:andraud"], ["lastname:andro"], ["firstname:clement"]]
```

But i need to use ma `position` attribut, for have something like (if i have respectively 0-0-1 in my position attribut :

```
[["lastname:andraud, lastname:andro"], ["firstname:clement"]]
```

If i try `$myEmptyArray[$data->getPosition()]` i have an error `"empty array"`

Thanks for help !

Comment: it returns empty array cuz the array has nothing in it and you are trying to fetch the elements from an empty array

Comment: i want to add element in an empty array so... what's the solution ?

Comment: The behavior you want is to concatenate with a ", " if the index is already set or go for an associative array style ? You can insert elements at any index of your array in php, however youll need to perform an "isset" if you loop through it using a counter.

Comment: `$myEmptyArray[$data->getPosition()] = array("name"=> $data->getName(), "value"=> $data->getValue());`

Comment: No, i need to add value, not replace each times

Comment: [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) **does not** put elements at a specific position. It puts them at the end of the array; whatever that means depends on the current content of the array. Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) first. You will discover that array elements can be accessed (for read or write) directly using the [square bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing): `$array['foo'] = 'bar'; echo ($array['foo']);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$myEmptyArray = array();

foreach($datas as $key => $data){
    $myEmptyArray[$data->getPosition()] =  array($data->getName() . ":" . $data->getValue() );
}
```

use custom keys instead of array_push. After that you can use with these keys. For your situation the kay will be positions.

```
print_r($myEmptyArray[$position_id]); // get by position id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myEmptyArray = array();
$temp_val = '';
$new_val = '';
foreach($datas as $key => $data){
    if(array_key_exists ( $data->getPosition() , $myEmptyArray )){
        $temp_val = $myEmptyArray[$data->getPosition()];
        $new_val = array($data->getName() . ":" . $data->getValue() );
        $myEmptyArray[$data->getPosition()] = $temp_val.','.$new_val;
    }else{
        $myEmptyArray[$data->getPosition()] =  array($data->getName() . ":" . $data->getValue() );
    }
}


print_r($myEmptyArray[$position_id]);
```

This code will save your record in array and it will not replace your values.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution :

```
    foreach($values as $key => $value){
        $name = $value->getName();

        if(!isset($array[$value->getPosition()])){
            $array[$value->getPosition()] = array();
        }

        array_push($array[$value->getPosition()],  $name . ":" . $value->getValue());
    }
```